# @sweetalert2 How to handle the error message in confirm if the network server is down on sweetalert2?

Tags: sweetalert, sweetalert2

how do you handle error messages in confirm if the network is down on sweetalert2?
i did it like the following code, please provide the solution

```js
const handleDownload = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Do you want to download?',
      icon: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
    }).then(result => {
      if (result.isConfirmed) {
        setDownloadLeaflet(id);
        downloadLeaflet({id, title}).then(() => setDownloadLeaflet(id));
        sendDownload({
          leafletId: id,
          recipient: null,
          type: 0,
        });
        Swal.fire('Downloaded!', 'Your file has been downloaded.', 'success');
      }
    });
  };
```

can display loading when the download process is in progress and display an error message if the server connection is down

Comment: Please post your code as text rather than as an image, and explain what happens in your current code vs what you want to happen.

Comment: Here is my code that has been updated sir

Comment: It sounds like your question is really about handling errors in general - it's not clear how sweetalert2 is really relevant here. To put it another way: if you were just trying to do the download and write to the console whether it was successful or not, would you know what to do? I'd expect the approach for sweetalert2 to be the same either way. I'm not a JavaScript developer, but I suspect a `.catch(...)` part is required in the line that starts `downloadLeaflet`.